# SQLTools Teradata Driver v0.4.0 Plugin is not getting registered

Tags: visual-studio-code, teradata, sqltools

It used to work earlier but suddenly one day this error popped up, and since then it always fails to get registered. Every other driver gets registered but this one.

Here's the log:

```
type here[1688627335831] INFO  (ext): SQLTools is starting
[1688627335833] INFO  (ext): initializing language client...
[1688627335834] INFO  (ext): Registering client for languages [{"scheme":"sqltools"},{"language":"sql","scheme":"untitled"},{"language":"sql","scheme":"file"},{"language":"sql","scheme":"sqltools"}]
    ns: "lc"
[1688627335837] INFO  (ext): loading plugins...
[1688627335837] INFO  (ext): registering Formatter Plugin.
    plugin: {
      "name": "Formatter Plugin"
    }
[1688627335837] INFO  (ext): registering Connection Manager Plugin.
    plugin: {
      "name": "Connection Manager Plugin"
    }
[1688627335837] INFO  (ext): registering CodeLens Plugin.
    plugin: {
      "name": "CodeLens Plugin",
      "registeredLanguages": []
    }
[1688627335838] INFO  (ext): registering Dependency Manager Plugin.
    plugin: {
      "name": "Dependency Manager Plugin",
      "installingDrivers": []
    }
[1688627335840] INFO  (ext): Connection explorer changed. Will be updated.
    ns: "conn-man:explorer"
[1688627335840] INFO  (ext): registering History Manager Plugin.
    plugin: {
      "name": "History Manager Plugin"
    }
[1688627335840] INFO  (ext): registering Bookmarks Manager Plugin.
    plugin: {
      "name": "Bookmarks Manager Plugin"
    }
[1688627335841] INFO  (ext): registering Authentication Provider Plugin.
    plugin: {
      "name": "Authentication Provider Plugin",
      "isRegistered": false
    }
[1688627335841] INFO  (ext): registering Object Drop-in Provider (plugin).
    plugin: {
      "type": "plugin",
      "name": "Object Drop-in Provider",
      "isRegistered": false
    }
[1688627335842] INFO  (ext): SQLTools activation completed. 10.505998 ms
[1688627335842] INFO  (ext): Formatter Plugin registered!
[1688627335842] INFO  (ext): CodeLens Plugin registered!
[1688627335842] INFO  (ext): Dependency Manager Plugin registered!
[1688627335842] INFO  (ext): Connection Manager Plugin registered!
[1688627335842] INFO  (ext): History Manager Plugin registered!
[1688627335842] INFO  (ext): Bookmarks Manager Plugin registered!
[1688627335842] INFO  (ext): Authentication Provider Plugin registered!
[1688627335842] INFO  (ext): Object Drop-in Provider (plugin) registered!
[1688627336015] INFO  (ext): registering Cassandra Driver Plugin (driver).
    plugin: {
      "extensionId": "JordanHury.sqltools-cassandra",
      "name": "Cassandra Driver Plugin",
      "type": "driver"
    }
[1688627336016] INFO  (ext): registering PostgreSQL/Cockroach Plugin (driver).
    plugin: {
      "extensionId": "mtxr.sqltools-driver-pg",
      "name": "PostgreSQL/Cockroach Plugin",
      "type": "driver"
    }
[1688627336098] INFO  (ext): registering SQLTools Teradata Driver Plugin (driver).
    plugin: {
      "extensionId": "ScriptPup.sqltools-teradata-driver",
      "name": "SQLTools Teradata Driver Plugin",
      "type": "driver"
    }
[1688627336188] INFO  (ls): SQLTools Server started!
===============================
Using node runtime?: no
ExecPath: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe 
===============================
[1688627336230] INFO  (ext): LanguageClient ready
    ns: "lc"
[1688627336230] INFO  (ls): Initialized with node version:v16.17.1
[1688627336267] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => ls/RegisterPlugin
[1688627336267] INFO  (ls): request to register plugin: "c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\jordanhury.sqltools-cassandra-0.2.3\out\ls\plugin.js"
[1688627336375] INFO  (ls): Driver cassandra registered!
    place: "driver-map"
    ns: "ls-context"
[1688627336376] INFO  (ls): Driver scylla registered!
    place: "driver-map"
    ns: "ls-context"
[1688627336376] INFO  (ext): Cassandra Driver Plugin (driver) registered!
[1688627336376] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => ls/RegisterPlugin
[1688627336376] INFO  (ls): request to register plugin: "c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\mtxr.sqltools-driver-pg-0.5.1\out\ls\plugin.js"
[1688627336415] INFO  (ls): Driver postgresql registered!
    place: "driver-map"
    ns: "ls-context"
[1688627336415] INFO  (ls): Driver aws redshift registered!
    place: "driver-map"
    ns: "ls-context"
[1688627336416] INFO  (ls): Driver cockroachdb registered!
    place: "driver-map"
    ns: "ls-context"
[1688627336416] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => ls/RegisterPlugin
[1688627336416] INFO  (ls): request to register plugin: "c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\scriptpup.sqltools-teradata-driver-0.4.0-win32-x64\out\ls\plugin.js"
[1688627336416] INFO  (ext): PostgreSQL/Cockroach Plugin (driver) registered!
[1688627336546] ERROR (ls): Error registering plugin: {}
    error: {}
[1688627336549] ERROR (ext): ERROR: Error loading plugin SQLTools Teradata Driver Plugin Request ls/RegisterPlugin failed with message: Error in native callback, {"code":-32603}
    ns: "error-handler"
[1688627337080] INFO  (ext): Connection explorer changed. Will be updated.
    ns: "conn-man:explorer"
[1688627337416] INFO  (ext): EXECUTING COMMAND => sqltools.refreshTree
[1688627337416] INFO  (ext): Connection explorer changed. Will be updated.
    ns: "conn-man:explorer"
[1688627337842] INFO  (ext): Connection explorer changed. Will be updated.
    ns: "conn-man:explorer"
[1688627339511] INFO  (ext): EXECUTING COMMAND => sqltools.showOutputChannel
```

I've tried disabling and enabling, reinstalling and whatnot, but nothing helped. An alternative to establish the connection (some other extension) might also help if you guys have one in mind.

Comment: Seems to be this issue https://github.com/ScriptPup/sqltools-teradata-driver/issues/25

Comment: I see. Looks like an issue of Node.js. Looks like I'll have to downgrade VS. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue tracked in this issue ticket: [VS Code Extension Installation Error #25](https://github.com/ScriptPup/sqltools-teradata-driver/issues/25).

At the time of this writing, [teradata-nodejs-driver does not support NodeJS 16](https://web.archive.org/web/20230712013402/https://www.npmjs.com/package/teradata-nodejs-driver#user-content-supported-platforms), which [VS Code switched to in version 1.78 when it updated to Electron 22](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_78#_electron-22-update)- specifically, NodeJS 16.17.1.

As a workaround, some users have chosen to downgrade to VS Code 1.77.